# Set Selected Value On Cascaded MVC Drop Down List

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I'm developing an MVC 5 application. Within a Razor View there are two drop down lists. When a value is selected from the first one (**productID**), a JQuery and Ajax call is made to return Json Data which populates the second drop down list (**additionalID**).

**Drop Downs**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.productID, Model.ProductList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.additionalID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#productID").change(ProductChange);

function ProductChange() {
        var val = $("#productID").val();
        var valText = $("#productID option:selected").text();
        if (val == 22 || val == 25 || val == 29 || val == 20) 
        {
            $('#AdditionalProducts').show('fast');
            $('label[for="additionalID"]').html('Please select a ' + valText + ' option');

            var dataPost = { productID: val };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Proposal/GetAdditionalProducts/',
                async: false, //This makes the JQuery below wait until $.ajax() call is finished
                data: dataPost,
                dataType: "json",
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred." + val);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = "";
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                    });

                    $("#additionalID").html(items);
                }
            });    
        }
        else
        {
            $('#additionalID').empty(); // clear drop down list
            $('#AdditionalProducts').hide('fast');
        }
    }
```

When editing a record, within the MVC Controller Edit Action I pass values for both **productID** and **additionalID** to the Razor View. Both drop downs appear, and the selected value for productID is set, however, the selected value for additionalID is not set.

Can anyone please help me with how to set the value of the second down drop list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting the an option to be selected when you first load the page? Your not rendering any options (by using `Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()`). You would need to include a separate `SelectList` property (say) AdditionalList that you assign in the controller that you use to render the initial options if `productID` has a value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi. Yes, I'm expecting the 2nd drop down to have a selected value when the page loads. I don't understand why I must include a separate `SelectList` property to render the options for the 2nd drop down list, these options are being rendered by my Ajax Call based on the ID passed in `$("#productID").change(ProductChange);` . But, even thought I pass the selected value for `additionalID` from my Controller, it still isn't set in the rendered options. ???

Comment: The options for the 2nd dropdown are not being rendered by the ajax call initially (unless you have called `$("#productID").trigger('change');` somewhere) and even if you do this, how would it know which option to select (your not setting the `selected` property anywhere). Note it's the `DropDownListFor()` helper which sets the selected property when it renders the html on the server.